# std::queue should I shrink to fit?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am considering to use `std::queue`(with `std::deque`) for FIFO structure.

In queue data structure, data only pushed in the back and popped in the front. 
Therefore, the memory in the front after popping an element will never be used.

I remember that std::vector does not release the memory until I explicitly call `shrink_to_fit` method.
What about `std::deque`?

So, should I consider releasing the memory in the front which will never be used again?

Comment: `std::vector` does not have to release any memory in a call to `shrink_to_fit`.

Comment: @juanchopanza Then, what is the purpose of the `shrink_to_fit` method?

Comment: @Sungmin: The purpose is that it is a hint to the implementation.

Comment: It is a non-binding request, so an implementation can decide whether to do it or not. Presumably it should make this choice based on some clever considerations. In any case, bear in mind that it would result in a re-allocation, which is definitely not for free.

Comment: `std::queue` does not have a `shrink_to_fit` method, and you can't call methods on the underlying container.  The thing you're asking if you should do, you can't do.  So what exactly is your question?

Comment: If your question is, rather, *"does std::deque release memory as elements are removed from the front?"* -- The answer is yes.  Not immediately, but eventually.

Comment: @juanchopanza that does not invalidate the OP's statement: vector does not release the memory until explicitly asked to.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley your assumption was right. That is my intention of the question. Thanks :)

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but... If the contents of the queue are cheap to copy, and the queue never becomes too big, you might find that `std::vector` is faster.  (And in general, regardless of the base type, you probably don't want to `shrink_to_fit` on a queue.  You want it to attain its maximum size, and that the memory for that size remains allocated.  The fact that there are no reallocations, after a while, is one of the things that makes vector faster than deque here.)

Comment: @juanchopanza Do any implementations actually take advantage of this freedom?  (Presumably, the intent is to allow the implementation to take into account the granularity of memory allocation.  Which would, in turn, suggest some sort of partial specialization on the object size.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't exactly need a `shrink_to_fit` for a queue, if it is used normally. `std::vector`'s `shrink_to_fit` is meant for situations where the vector content has diminished by a huge amount, so that it actually has a benefit to call the (rather costly) reallocation in order to free that huge amount of memory. It is in general not needed if the vector has a short lifetime or if its size does not vary too much.

Having said that, a `std::deque` is a different kind of beast. It *typically* consists of fixed-size chunks of memory. If you erase lots of elements from the deque, the chunks that no longer contain any elements can/will be deallocated. So the biggest memory overhead you can have at any time is a bit under twice the chunk size, e.g. if the queue contains only two elements, one at the end of a chunk, the second at the start of the next chunk. Therefore, `std::deque::shrink_to_fit` can only move the elements of the deque in a way that frees exactly one chunk, wich is not a big gain (iirc a typical implementation has a chunk size of a few kb).

These are very general statements that might not apply in memory critical situations. But as *standard* containers, neither vector not deque are explicitly designed to be used in such exetreme situations. If memory footprint is an issue in the part of the program where you use the queue, you might want to use yet another data structure.

Comment: Thanks. It explains everything I wanted to know :)

Comment: Do you even have a `shrink_to_fit` method on `std::deque`?  (I don't have a copy of C++11 on this machine to verify, but I wouldn't expect it to be present.)

Comment: @JamesKanze there is an `std::deque::shrink_to_fit` method. Unfortunately I don't have a C++11 implementation that I can look at here.

Comment: @juanchopanza uh, did not know that the method actually exists. I updated my answer accordingly. Is there actually a need for it?

Comment: @ArneMertz That's my question as well.  It's likely to be very expensive, shifting all of the elements in the deque, for very little gain.  (The most obvious use case for it in vector is when you've done a very large `reserve`, to avoid extra reallocations when filling it with an unknown number of elements, and are then willing to pay the cost of one reallocation, to recover all of the unused memory.)

Answer (score 8):

The memory allocation characteristics of `std::deque` are implementation defined. The standard has no *specific* requirement on when memory is allocated or released as far as `deque`s are concerned. The asymptotic requirements on insertion, deletion, and access performance force implementations along certain lines. But there can be much variation within that.

*Generally speaking*, if you pop enough things from the front of a `deque`, a memory deallocation will happen.